# Code printing extra memory garbage

Tags: c, clang++

This code is printing extra memory garbage instead. How could I fix it?
In this code I'm trying to remove 10% of the price (that will be inserted by the user).

```
if (value == 1){
    int price = 0;
    int price_final = (price - (price - 0.01);
    printf ("INSERT A PRICE >> ");
    scanf ("%d", &price);
    printf ("Final value %d", price_final);
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile due to lack of `)`.

Comment: This code is trying to do floating point operations (`- 0.01`) on integer variables. It's also reading user input via `scanf()`, which is *bound* to return the OP to SO later on. ;-)

Comment: Even if the error is fixed, the `price` user inputted won't be taken care of by the calculation of `price_final`.

Comment: Post a [mcve]! That does not compile and has quite some flaws. Please first try yourself to get your code run. "my code does not work" is **no** specific problem statement!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the computation (`int price_final = (price - (price - 0.01);` before you obtain the value of `price`. This is how the code should be:

```
if (value == 1) {
    float price = 0, price_final;

    printf ("INSERT A PRICE >> ");
    if (scanf ("%f", &price) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid price");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    price_final = price - (price - 0.01);
    printf ("Final value %f\n", price_final);
}
```

You're also subtracting a `float`(0.01) from an `int`, which is undefined, so I changed both variables to `float`.

Also, I'd recommend that you read a line first with `fgets` and parse the string using `sscanf`:

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, 99, stdin);
int price;

if (sscanf(line, "%d", &price) == 0)
    handle error
```

Comment: The code that you posted will only produce garbage due to a float operation beeing performed on an int. That behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove 10% of the user given price. So Your calculation would be like this 
        x=y-(y*0.1); where y is given price and x is new price.
Here is code:

```
if (value == 1) {
    float price = 0, price_final;

    printf ("INSERT A PRICE >> ");
    if (scanf ("%f", &price) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid price");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    price_final = price - (price * 0.1);
    printf ("Final value %f\n", price_final);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this.

First:

```
int price_final = (price - (price - 0.01);
```

You are performing floating point operations on an integer, which is undefined.

Second:

You are calculating the new price before you even read in the user price. Thats nonsensical and `price` will always assume `0` in your code.

Third:

```
int price_final = (price - (price - 0.01);
```

Is missing a closing bracket ')'

There may be more, but these three are blatantly obvious.